# Flash As3 Mute Button problems

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, mute

I am trying to create a UI movie clip that can be used across different scenes. 
It uses variables from the root scope to determine states.

When i press the mute button is works fine, however when i try to un-mute things go weird. Sometimes it takes 2 clicks to unmute, sometimes more. It seems random. 
Muting however seems to work first time..

Any ideas?

---

```
Main Timeline: 

var mute:Boolean = false;
var playerName = "Fred";


function setMute(vol)
{
    var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(1,0);
    sTransform.volume = vol;
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = sTransform;
}

function toggleMuteBtn(event:Event)
{
    if (mute)
    {
        // Sound On, Mute Off
        mute = false;
        setMute(1);
        ui_mc.muteCross_mc.visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Sound Off, Mute On
        mute = true;
        setMute(0);
        ui_mc.muteCross_mc.visible = true;
    }
}
```

---

```
ui_mc Action Script:

if (MovieClip(parent).mute == false)
{
    muteCross_mc.visible = false;
}

mute_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, MovieClip(parent).toggleMuteBtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your code is on the first frame of your timeline.

I won't go into depth with the issues regarding that practice in as3, but you might be better off using a document class. That way the code is initialized only once. I'm guessing when you're switching between the scenes, you keep re-initializing, so you end up resetting mute to false.

To check if this is happening, just add a `trace("init")` to that script, and see how often you call that., you can also add a trace to your toggleMuteBtn function to see what the mute variable is before you change it.

*on a side note, I'm curious why you're typecasting the parent`MovieClip(parent)` though it won't cause any problems, there is no need for it as you could just use `parent`*